# Random Post ruining my Wordpress comments section

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I currently have this code on my template:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'offset' => 1);
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : ?>
<li><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2><p><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</p></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

The nature of the code is to generate a list of [Random post from](http://www.bendaggers.com/add-related-post-in-blogger-using-linkwithin/) blog post. The problem is, the code starts ruining my comments section by displaying the wrong list of comments to unrelated blog post.

*see my sample on the link above*

The common sense to do, is to remove to code in my template. My question is any ideas on how to fix the code above so i can still use it?

Comment: It's just a guess, but try to change the name of the variable $post in the foreach loop. It could be, that you overwrite the already existing $post variable of the current article.

Comment: @axel.michel: Actually it needs to be overwriten (using `the_title();` etc. here which uses the global variable `$post`).

Comment: there's something wrong with the code below posted by @axel.michel. can someone correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you work with get_posts, and you need to override the $post, you'll have to do it like this:

```
<?php
global $post;
$tmp_post = $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'offset' => 1);
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : ?>
    <li><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2><p><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </p></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php $post = $tmp_post; // reset the $post to the original ?>
```

Comment: The Random post is already working in my wordpress theme, thank you @axel.michael. you can refer to my site http://www.bendaggers.com/